# VS Code Paste Problem, the sequence was messed up

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-code, copy, settings, paste

when i tried to paste the below code inside the VS code MongoDB shell to the terminal, the whole sequence was messed up, the format should be correct as I paste it to another place, and the sequence is all fine

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5PHv.png)

```js
db.misCourse.insert([
    {title: "MongoDB Overview",description: "MongoDB is no SQL database",by: "MongoDB Tutorial",url: "http://www.mongodb.com",tags: ["mongodb", "database", "NoSQL"],likes: 100},
    {title: "NoSQL Database",description: "NoSQL database doesn't have tables",by: "MongoDB Tutorial",url: "http://www.mongodb.com",tags: ["mongodb", "database", "NoSQL"],likes: 20,comments: [
    {user:"user1",message: "My first comment",dateCreated: new Date(2020,11,10,2,35),like: 0}]} ])
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LiWXa.png)

when i try to paste below code inside the VS code to terminal, all the sequence was messing up, the format should be correct as i paste it to other place, the sequence are all fine, what should i do to solve this pasting problem?